# JQuery Image Gallery - Selected Images Temporarily Changes Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple Ecommerce product gallery. Whenever the user clicks the thumbnail the images load correctly, but for a second the layout will shift positions because the image is swapping with the selected image. Would anybody know a way to clean up my code where this does not happen? I'm new to Jquery, so i'm probably not doing this the right way.

```
 $(function() {
    $(".image").click(function() {
    var image = $(this).attr("rel");
    $('#image').hide();
    $('#image').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#image').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
    return false;
        });
    });
```

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dshojaei/gwpc89av/)

Comment: This happens mostly when you rapidly click a thumbnail or double click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't hide `#image` instead the `img` inside it.

And i have added `fadeOut` instead of hiding to make it look more smooth. Then do `fadeIn` in the callback of `fadeOut`

```
$(function() {
    $(".image").click(function() {
       var image = $(this).attr("rel");
       $('#image img').fadeOut("slow", function(){
           $('#image').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');
           $('#image').fadeIn('slow');
       });
       return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Void. That looks much better. Still have a lot of work to-do on this one. :)